# toggleClass not working in ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Hello Im new on stackoverflow, i have this GET method its work fine i mean i get a respone from server but i toggleClass is not working i dont know why ?

this is my code:

```
$("#form1").on("click", function() {
  var user = $("#form1 input.user").val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "admin.php?user=" + user,
    type: "GET",
    beforeSend: function() {},
    success: function(res) {
      $("#results").html(res);
      $("#results .name").toggleClass('.active');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont need a `dot` just remove it from your code
change

```
$("#results .name").toggleClass('.active');
```

to

```
$("#results .name").toggleClass('active');
```

Comment: im noob :(, thanx for help